# Rename a Mapped Network Drive via CMD

Tags: windows-7, command-line, script

I map a network drive via command line.  Once this drive is mapped, it appears under My Computer with the full path.

How can I rename the mapped drive using command prompt?

I have used the "full path name of the folder" & "new name of the folder" command, which works perfectly but when I use it to rename the drive, it does not work.

Comment: Do you mean, change the drive letter?

Comment: Nope. I mean the label of the drive letter. The name itself. Not the letter. Like this, Client (\\192.168.1.100) (z:) .... I want to rename it with only Client will show and the drive letter...

Comment: Renaming it and removing the ip address MANUALLY will totally work. But I want to apply it using the comman prompt because I will further code it using JAVA. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be two approaches, both listed in this [question/answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/56898/how-to-change-mapped-drive-label-from-command-line) at ServerFault.  I much prefer the VBScript approach, which is also described [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/change-label-network-drive-t1581395.html).

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
oShell.NameSpace("H:\").Self.Name = "your_label"
```

So I would create a small VBScript script, which takes the drive letter as one parameter, and the new label as the second.  My VBScript is rusty, but according to this Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469754/how-to-pass-and-access-command-line-arguments-in-vbscript), something like this:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
oShell.NameSpace(WScript.Arguments.Item(0)).Self.Name = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)
```

If you call that rename_drive.vbs, you can execute it as

```
wscript rename_drive.vbs H:\ new_drive_name
```

Of course, if you're comfortable creating COM objects from Java, you can do that directly.

Comment: +1 because the answer seems useful.  (Not that I have taken the time to test it.)  [History](http://superuser.com/posts/670904/revisions) shows [Community](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) bumped this question, which led to me giving it a bit of attention, and deemed the effort worthwhile.  Good job, thanks.  You could also use cscript instead of wscript.  (Since there are no message boxes, presumably the normal result is that this would just successfully accomplish the task identically regardless of which command was used.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the VBScript approach, you can also perform the same operation using PowerShell.

```sh
function Set-DriveName($Drive, $Name){
    (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace($Drive).Self.Name = $Name
}
```

And then use the function

```sh
Set-DriveName -Drive "Y:" -Name "Drive Name"
```

Alternatively, if you want to launch this from CMD or from another application, you can use this command:

```sh
powershell -c "(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace('Y:').Self.Name = 'Drive Name'"
```

**PLEASE NOTE:** Do not run this command as Administrator if you're trying to rename mapped drives visible only to the local user. You need to run this command in the context of the target user where the target drive appears.